# How do I change one side of split viewport to rendered view?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I upgraded to Blender 2.8 and I'm running into problems with the UI. In the previous version, I could easily split the viewport and view one side as the rendered/finished animation while I'm editing.

I know how to split the screen in 2.8, but I'm not able to change the right side to rendered view. When I click render>view render (underlined in red in pic), it changes the left side to the render. Also, I accidentally started the actual render so now when I click 'view render' it shows the partial/cancelled rendering, not what I'm editing in real time.

[image]

How do I change the right side of my split viewport to rendered view to view my changes while I'm editing?

Comment: use the Z key to change to rendered mode, ^ that is for viewing rendered image.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot, that was easy! Thanks for your input.